# Geonode extracting attribute

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

[image]Hey!
I want to capture attribute that will allow me to extract data from the geometry, I want to use the data in the shader tab - gradiant, random ext
*I did not create the geometry within geo node (just the shortest path)

Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.
Normally you would use Capture Attribute and then read it out in the Shader Editor via Attribute node, but it doesn't work, no matter which method I tried. I am using Blender 3.5.1 which is kind of experimental at this point in time.
If you try this in an earlier version of Blender, does it work then?

Comment: use the store attribute node